# PHFacebook Framework: How to write something to facebook?

Tags: cocoa, facebook-graph-api

while looking for a Cocoa Facebook Framework that works with OSX I found PHFacebook.

http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=107

It's really nice and works well but the sample app is only able to read from Facebook. Can someone please explain to me how I can write something to facebook using PHFacebook? On the Developers homepage someone asked the same Question and the developer answered:

"I’m sure it’s possible, I just never tried. Did you add the “write” property to the request? Maybe that’s all you’re missing. The sample app only has “read”."

But I can't find any "read" property in the code. Can someone please give me a hint?

Thank you so much!

CaptnCrash

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to upload the image to facebook, then, I used the ***phfacebook*** to get the access_token, and then used the ***ASIhttprequest*** to upload the image.

You can see the detail at
[Facebook Graph API Upload Local Image to Wall (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333792/facebook-graph-api-upload-local-image-to-wall-objective-c)